# IBAction makes errors on theos compiling

Tags: ios7, hook, cydia, tweak, theos

I'm new to Objective-C programming and I want to make a simple tweak about VLC for iOS.app but I can't compile.
Here's my code :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

%hook VLCMovieViewController

-(IBAction)playPause
{
    if([_mediaPlayer isPlaying]) {
        UIAlertView *pause = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"PAUSED" message:@"Your movie is paused" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK !", nil];
        [_listPlayer pause];
        [pause show];
        [pause release];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *play = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"PLAYING" message:@"Your movie is playing" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK !", nil];
        [_listPlayer play];
        [play show];
        [play release];
    }
}

%end
```

I don't find any mistakes in my codes but when I try to compile, theos returns me an error :

```
Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
Compiling Tweak.xm...
Tweak.xm:6:8: error: expected unqualified-id
static IBAction (*_logos_orig$_ungrouped$VLCMovieViewController$playPause)(VLCMovieViewController*, SEL); s...
       ^
<built-in :24:22: note: expanded from here
#define IBAction void)__attribute__((ibaction)
                     ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [obj/Tweak.xm.708dff35.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [VLCTweak.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

Have you any clue to make it working ?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use IBAction with Theos, as you don't use Interface Builder.
IBAction is only a way to tell Xcode and Interface Builder to link UI elements to your code.
Replacing -(IBAction)playPause by -(void)playPause should work